# Regular expressions in Java to extract index posting list

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a pattern that will let me extract information from a string that looks like this:

```
(10, [(1, 4482729), (2, 4395402), (10, 4390557), (1, 4520185)])
```

It is a fixed number Z at the start (e.g. 10) followed by N pairs in the form (X, Y), where N can be any number.

EDIT:

What I tried so far:

```
Pattern.compile("[(]\\d+[,]\\s+\\[(*)\\][)]")
```

I need to extract the X and Y from all of these pairs, and Z.

Comment: And what's the question plus your efforts so far?

Comment: You need to post what you've tried so far that isn't working so that people can help you.

Comment: No need to downvote so fast, a comment is enough... I'm still trying to learn regex

Comment: Why not use `\d+` to match all numbers?

Comment: [It doesn't look nice](http://ideone.com/bgXgzA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
String pattern = "\\(\\d+, \\[[\\(\\d+, \\d+\\), ]*\\(\\d+, \\d+\\)\\]\\)";
```

I tested it like this:

```
String pattern = "\\(\\d+, \\[[\\(\\d+, \\d+\\), ]*\\(\\d+, \\d+\\)\\]\\)";
String test = "(10, [(1, 4482729), (2, 4395402), (10, 4390557), (1, 4520185)])";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
boolean b = m.matches();
System.out.println(b);
```

And it worked fine.